# Problems setting correct timeinterval for Expo local Notifications on iOS

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo

I'm setting a notification in React Native for Android and iOS - the code below works fine for Android, but for iOS the timestamp comes out very strange - and the notification does not show as a result

Code (directly from https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/):

```
 async function setNewReminder() {

    const trigger = new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
    trigger.setMinutes(0);
    trigger.setSeconds(0);

    const identifier = await Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({
            content: {
                title: 'Happy new hour!',
            },          
          trigger,
    });
    // notificationID.current = `${identifier}`
  }
```

See the iOS timestamp below (`trigger.seconds`):

```js
LOG  [
  {
    "content": {
      "attachments": [Array],
      "badge": null,
      "body": null,
      "categoryIdentifier": "",
      "data": [Object],
      "launchImageName": "",
      "sound": null,
      "subtitle": null,
      "summaryArgument": "",
      "summaryArgumentCount": 0,
      "targetContentIdentifier": null,
      "threadIdentifier": "",
      "title": "Testing trigger"
    },
    "identifier": "b247c5c6-c6ff-4cbf-a794-3c81dbe7886f",
    "trigger": {
      "class": "UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger",
      "repeats": false,
      "seconds": 14489.274579048157,
      "type": "timeInterval"
    }
  }
]
```

When I try the trigger as a non specific date, e.g. 20 seconds in the future, the notification triggers properly.

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this timestamp?

Comment: Have you tried initializing the date in a simpler way: `const trigger = new Date(); trigger.setHours(trigger.getHours() + 1); trigger.setMinutes(0); trigger.setSeconds(0);`